# Getting HP dragonfly G4 to work under linux : webcam

Tags: linux, webcam

I just got a "HP Dragonfly 13.5 inch G4 Notebook PC" without operating system hoping to run some flavor of GNU/Linux on it. I've tried Ubuntu 22.04 and Manjaro but both seem to have similar issues. Here I am addressing the issues with the internal webcam

It is initially not recognized at all. It seems to be a general problem with [Intel * Lake ipu6 cameras](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-bins). Tried to install he code from this link repositories but install failed  due to issues with the compiling flags for https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal :

> Dans le fichier inclus depuis /usr/include/inttypes.h:25,
> depuis /home/cbarbu/Téléchargements/ipu6-camera-hal/src/metadata/icamera_metadata_base.cpp:20:
>
> /usr/include/features.h:414:4: erreur: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE
>
> requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Werror=cpp]   414 | #
> warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
> |    ^~~~~~~

This error is repeated 10 times for different files and then I have

> cc1plus : tous les avertissements sont traités comme des erreurs
> make[2](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal/issues/19#issuecomment-1687998803): *** [CMakeFiles/hal_adaptor.dir/build.make:202:
> CMakeFiles/hal_adaptor.dir/home/cbarbu/Téléchargements/ipu6-camera-hal/src/iutils/ScopedAtrace.cpp.o]
> Error 1 make[2](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal/issues/19#issuecomment-1687998803): *** Attente des tâches non terminées....

And then finally :

> make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
>
> ###############   build_hal_adaptor  FAIL   #############

As indicated in the [bug report for this repository](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal/issues/19#issuecomment-1687998803), adding

> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

in build.sh, function build_hal_adaptor() {

so that cmake call looks like

> command cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR/install ../

Allowed to compile smoothly build_hal_adaptor.
Unfortunately, one more issue :

> autoreconf: error: 'configure.ac' is required
>
> ./build.sh: ligne 149: ./configure: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
>
> ###############   build_icamerasrc  FAIL   #############

The problem was actually that the icamerasrc folder was not on the right branch :

> git checkout icamerasrc_slim_api

Did take car of it, but the computer still is not detecting the internal webcam.

Comment: Why did you tagged this with "virtualbox"?

Comment: @changanAuto Sorry I was making at the same time two different questions about the virtualization and the sound on the same computer, I corrected the tags. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: You should also [edit] the question and post the full error messages. Of course, before even starting, makes sure you have all the dependencies installed.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://www.linux.org/threads/hp-dragonfly-g3-webcam.44992/ ? one suggestion is that there's a lock on webcam to prevent unauthorized use.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you, I hadn't seen this thread, I'll check it up asap.

Comment: The error messages should be in English